# wrapAll 3 class elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

I'm stuck with trying to capsulate 3 divs inside one wrapping div. So far I have managed to get 2 divs wrapped up, but I can't figure out the last one.

You can see my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cz9eY/

```
$('.input_jq_checkbox').each(function(){
$(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="test"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$(this).nextAll(':lt(2)').andSelf()` you'll get the label and the next two elements.